# Association finding wrong table

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to get contain the Children of my DomainTypes table for my DomainTypes view() function but it is complaining with "Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Children.domain_type_id' in 'where clause'" The problem is that my DomainTypes table doesn't have a domain_type_id column. The Domain table does. Here is the code for my DomainTypes view():

```
public function view($id) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid DomainType'));
    }

    $domainType = $this->DomainTypes
        ->find()
        ->where(['DomainTypes.id' => $id])
        ->contain(['Parent', 'Children', 'Affiliates'])
        ->first();

    $this->set(compact('domainType'));
}
```

So a little about my setup. I have 2 tables, Domains and DomainTypes. Both use the Tree behavior.

Here is the initialize code for the Domain Table:

```
public function initialize(array $config){
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->addBehavior('Tree');

    //Associations
    $this->hasMany('Children', [
        'className' => 'Domains',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Parent', [
        'className' => 'Domains',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Affiliates');
    $this->belongsTo('DomainTypes');
}
```

And here is the initialize code for the DomainTypes Table:

```
public function initialize(array $config){
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->addBehavior('Tree');

    //Associations
    $this->hasMany('Children', [
        'className' => 'DomainTypes',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Parent', [
        'className' => 'DomainTypes',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Affiliates');
    $this->hasMany('Domains');
}
```

Both very similar but also clearly defining which className to use. Why is Cakephp 3 assuming there is a domain_type_id column on my DomainTypes table? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I wasn't paying attention properly, and CakePHP seems to be actually correct when it auto-generates a foreign key named `domain_type_id`, it's a `hasMany` association and so the FK should be based on the source table.

The solution is still the same, the FK needs to be set explictly, and as already figured by @MjGaiser the `parent_id` for the `belongsTo` association isn't necessary, and instead the FK for the `hasMany` association should use `parent_id` instead of `child_id`:

```
    $this->hasMany('Children', [
        'className' => 'DomainTypes',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Parent', [
        'className' => 'DomainTypes'
    ]);
```

Comment: That that would make sense if I was only using belongsTo relationships, but there isn't supposed to be a "child_id" since hasMany is supposed to use the childrens parent_id. If you had both a parent_id and a child_id you would be duplicating data and opening your site up to a lot more issues. Or am I not understanding where you are going?

Comment: @MjGaiser No, you're right, I just wasn't paying attention properly, there should be no `child_id`, and CakePHP generating a FK named `domain_type_id` seems to be correct actually. I'll update my answer and remove the nonsense :)

Answer (score 0):

We were both close, but not quite right. ndm, your answer was helpful though as it did point to another mistake I was making. The final association code should look like this:

```
    $this->hasMany('Children', [
        'className' => 'DomainTypes',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Parent', [
        'className' => 'DomainTypes',
    ]);
```

When I was trying to enter the foreign key, Instead of "foreignKey", I was using "foreign_key"  which was pretty much useless. Thanks for the help ndm.